# The number of ways to count the votes

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, catalan-numbers

**The question is :Given two candidates that got n votes each , what is the number of ways to count the 2n votes while one candidate is leading all the time.**

I tried to solve it using Catalan numbers but I'm not sure about the way i'm thinking I thought that the it's equal to start in the grid from (1,0) to (n+1,n) in this way both the candidates are having n votes at the end and the number of ways to do this without touching the diagonal are equal to   $\frac{1}{n+1}\ * \binom{2n}{n} $ .

Comment: I think we also need two multiply by 2 because we don't know who is leading

Comment: I think from $(1,0)$ to $(n, n-1)$ as you must touch the diagonal at $(0,0)$ and $(n,n)$.  Try with $n=2$ to see if you get the right answer; I think there is only one possibility (or two if you can reverse the candidates)

Comment: @Henry indeed ! it must touch the diagonal at (0,0) and (n,n) , thank you very much but i'm a bit new to Catalan numbers can write the final answer.

Comment: I think the correct answer is thanks to Henry is $\frac{2}{n}\ * \binom{2(n-1)}{n-1} $